# How can i make a Number Format Like 000"+"000 in android

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, decimalformat

I want to make a number format like 000"+"000. The rule will be 3 digits "+" 3 digits. I will give you some examples below.

I have tried some codes before i will show them below. I think i have to use NumberFormat class. My codes are below. by the way my number maximum have 6 digits if number has less digits the missing digits(which will be in left), has to be 0.

I tried

```java
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("000'+'000");
```

but it gave error which is

Unquoted special character '0' in pattern "000'+'000"

but it was worked when i make

```java
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("'+'000");
```

or

```java
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("000'+'");
```

So simply i can make number-plus or plus-number but i can't make number(3 digit)-plus-number(3 digit)

I expect to get these outputs for these inputs:

> input: 4032
>
> output: 004+032
>
> input : 5
>
> output: 000+005
>
> input: 123450
>
> output: 123+450
>
> input: 10450
>
> output: 010+450

Comment: One solution would be `String format = String.format("%06s"); String result = format.substring(0, 3) + "+" + format.substring(3);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a trick: change the grouping separator symbol to `+`:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('+');
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("000,000", symbols);

int x = 3250;
System.out.println(nf.format(x));
```

Result:

```
003+250
```

Or use a method like this:

```
public static String specialFormat(int number) {
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("000");
    return nf.format(number / 1000) + "+" + nf.format(number % 1000);
}
```

it formats separately the 3 first digits and the 3 last digits and concatenates with a `+` in the middle.
Use it:

```
int x = 5023;
System.out.println(specialFormat(x));
```

Result:

```
005+023
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not a decimal syntax. Therefor, you cannot use the DecimalFormat, because it handles all kinds of localized numbers but not arbitrary ones like yours. However, you might want to implement your own java.text.Format.

Answer (score 0):

What about using this kind of method and later convert it to the format you want

```
generateNumbers(String val) {
    int len = val.length();
    String finalValue;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    if (len < 6) {
        for (int i = 6; i > len; i--) {
            sb.append("0");
        }
        finalValue = sb.append(val).toString();
    } else {
        finalValue = val;
    }
    System.out.println(finalValue.substring(0, 3) + "+" + finalValue.substring(3));
}
```

for testing you can call this

```
generateNumbers("4032");
generateNumbers("5");
generateNumbers("123450");
generateNumbers("10450");
```

Output is

```
004+032
000+005
123+450
010+450
```

Let me know if it's useful.